# Erro na exclusão de um usuário usando $_SESSION['']. Ele continua no sistema mesmo depois de sua exclusão

Tags: php

Acabei de fazer login usuário, excluiu o próprio usuário logado no sistema, acontece que ao invés de ser redirecionado para fora dele ainda estou nele.

O que eu fiz?

1 - Acessei a página de excluir funcionário.

2 - Escolhi eu mesmo, o formulário me redirecionou para uma outra página que fez a exclusão

3 - Nesse página da operação de exclusão me redireciona para a página que lista todos os funcionários

4 - Era pra eu ser redirecionado para fora, porém ainda estou no sistema

Esse aqui é o trecho de meu código de `$_SESSION` que controla a permanência do usuário no sistema, se tiver como melhorar ele seria ótimo (esse trecho está em todas as páginas do meu sistema.

```
<?php

    require(__DIR__ . '/conexao/conexao.php');
    require(__DIR__ . '/classe/classe_usuario.php');

    session_start();

    if((isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'])) && (!empty($_SESSION['id_usuario']))){
        echo "Olá " . $_SESSION['nome_usuario'] . "!";
    } else {
        echo "<script> alert('Ação inválida, entre no sistema da maneira correta.'); location.href='/web/index.php' </script>";
        die;
    }
?>
```

// Página que faz a exclusão e redireciona para a página de listagem de usuários

```
<?php
    require_once '../conexao/conexao.php'; 
    require_once '../classe/classe_usuario.php';
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['id_usuario']) && isset($_SESSION['nome_usuario'])){
        echo "Olá " . $_SESSION['nome_usuario'] . "!";
    } else {
        echo "<script> alert('Ação inválida, entre no sistema da maneira correta.'); location.href='/web/index.php' </script>";
        die;
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> DELETE | FUNCIONÁRIO </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/web/css/css.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['Deletar'])){
            $cd_funcionario = $_POST['cd_funcionario'];
            try {
                $remove = "DELETE FROM funcionario WHERE cd_funcionario = :cd_funcionario";
                $remocao = $conexao->prepare($remove);
                $remocao->bindValue(':cd_funcionario',$cd_funcionario);
                $remocao->execute();
                // Retorna para a pagina de formulario de listagem
                header('Location: ../form_crud/form_select_funcionario.php');
            } catch (PDOException $falha_remocao) {
                echo "A remoção não foi feita".$falha_remocao->getMessage();
                die;
            } catch (Exception $falha) {
                echo "Erro não característico do PDO".$falha->getMessage();
                die;
            }
        } else {
            echo "Ocorreu algum erro ao finalizar a operação, refaça novamente a operação.";
            echo '<p><a href="../form_crud/form_delete_funcionario.php" title="Refazer operação"><button>Refazer operação</button></a></p>';
            exit;
        }   
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Esse trecho está em todas as páginas de meu sistema, eu preciso fazer algo no meu arquivo que faz a exclusão do funcionário pra funcionar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está excluindo o usuário mas não apagou a sessão

```
  $remove = "DELETE FROM funcionario WHERE cd_funcionario = :cd_funcionario";
            $remocao = $conexao->prepare($remove);
            $remocao->bindValue(':cd_funcionario',$cd_funcionario);
            $remocao->execute();
            // antes de redirecionar destrua a sessão
            session_destroy();
            // Retorna para a pagina de formulario de listagem
            header('Location: ../form_crud/form_select_funcionario.php');
```

Comment: Que estranho, logei como ADM pra excluir um outro usuário, excluiu o usuário que queria, porém eu como ADM sai do sistema.

Comment: Mas deu isso ai certo.

Comment: Se você destroi a sessão você é deslogado do sistema uma vez que verifica sessão ativa.
O código era do jeito que estava pois não faz sentido logar com um usuário e excluir ele mesmo.

Comment: Dependendo da sua regra, você pode verificar de é adm e caso seja não destruir a sessão. E caso tenha resolvido seu problema, seria legal marcar como resposta correta (:

Comment: Vou fazer um if que se identifica que o usuário for ADM ou gerente ele não sai do sistema, apenas retorne para a página de listagem com a sessão intacta.